# How can I generate a random unicode character in Swift?

Tags: swift, random, unicode, character

My current attempts at creating a random unicode character generate have failed with errors such as those mentioned in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158381/fatal-error-high-and-low-surrogate-code-points-are-not-valid-unicode-scalar-va). It's obviously not as simple as just generating a random number.

**Question:** How can I generate a random unicode character in Swift?

Comment: It should be possible roughly like this: 1. find a random number from the Unicode range you want the character to be in 2. [get the character corresponding with that number](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/playing-with-primitives-characters.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unicode Scalar Value](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value)

> Any Unicode code point except high-surrogate and low-surrogate code
>   points. In other words, the ranges of integers 0 to D7FF and E000
>   to 10FFFF inclusive.

So, I've made a small code's snippet. See below.

#### This code works

```
func randomUnicodeCharacter() -> String {
    let i = arc4random_uniform(1114111)
    return (i > 55295 && i < 57344) ? randomUnicodeCharacter() : String(UnicodeScalar(i))
}
randomUnicodeCharacter()
```

#### This code ***doesn't*** work!

```
let N: UInt32 = 65536
let i = arc4random_uniform(N)
var c = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
print(c, appendNewline: false)
```

I was a little bit confused with [this](http://www.danshort.com/unicode/) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters). [Maximum value: 65535]

Comment: And what exactly is `N` supposed to be?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform()` will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound. Therefore, let N: UInt32 = 65536.

Comment: This method is faulty. I just encountered this error: `fatal error: high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values`

Comment: I've created a separate question for this error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158381/fatal-error-high-and-low-surrogate-code-points-are-not-valid-unicode-scalar-va).

Comment: @VatsalManot I've found my mistake, one second pls

Answer (score 0):

```
static func randomCharacters(withLength length: Int = 20) -> String {
    let base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    var randomString: String = ""

    for _ in 0..<length {
        let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(base.characters.count))
        randomString += "\(base[base.index(base.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(randomValue))])"
    }
    return randomString
}
```

Here you can modify length (Int) and use this for generating random characters.