# fatal error: high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values

Tags: string, swift, unicode, utf-16, utf

Sometimes while initializing a `UnicodeScalar` with a value like `57292` yields the following error:

```
fatal error: high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values
```

What is this error, why does it occur and how can I prevent it in the future?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @ruakh: Done. Added example value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Background: UTF-16 represents a sequence of Unicode characters ("code points") as a sequence of 16-bit "code units". For characters whose scalar values fit within 16 bits (i.e., those from U+0000 to U+FFFF), the code unit has the same value as the character; but for characters outside that range (those from U+10000 to U+10FFFF), UTF-16 has to use two code units. To make this work, Unicode reserves a range of code-points (U+D800 to U+DFFF) as "surrogates", which cannot be used as characters; UTF-16 can then use two of these surrogates together to represent a code point outside the 16-bit range. (The "high" and "low" refer to surrogates that serve as the *first* and *second* code units in these pairs, respectively. Each surrogate is either a high surrogate or a low surrogate, but not both; experience with older character sets had shown that it's very useful to always be able to tell where one character ends and the next begins.)

So the issue you're seeing is that you're trying to create a `UnicodeScalar` with a value (U+DFCC) that, according to the Unicode standard, is reserved to *not* be a Unicode scalar. U+DFCC is defined not to exist, and is just a "surrogate" for half of a scalar that does exist.

To prevent this issue, you need to stick to scalars that do exist — U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+10FFFF.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Actually, the surrogates range is U+D800 to U+DFFF, right?

Comment: @fumoboy007: Whoops, right! Fixed now, thanks!